# Cannot display ObjectGears page

Tags: objectgears

I cannot display ObjectGears Page. In the event log there is:

Method not found: 'Int32 Com.ObjectGears.Common.BusinessLayers.LogBL.Write(System.Exception)'
at Com.ObjectGears.Module.MultiEdit.MultiEditWebPart.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

It looks like an error caused by MultiEditWebpart. Can I do something with the page to correct it? It goes to error when I try to open the page design and remove the webpart multiedit.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the page design and remove the erroneous webpart if you go to the module containing the webpart, change its code, save and reinitialize the module. After this the page design will be available. After you remove the webpart go to the module again, change the code to the former value, save and reinitialize.
This will make other functionality using the module working again.